# SQL Server STRING_AGG and group by for column in one table but not for a column in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

The title probably poorly describes the problem.

I am working with the [Microsoft Pubs](https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/tree/master/samples/databases/northwind-pubs) database. The goal is to display all the titles with their author names and publishers. So, I came up with this:

```
select dt.title, STRING_AGG(CONCAT(da.au_fname, ' ', da.au_lname), ', ') as 'author name', dp.pub_name
from dbo.titles dt
left join dbo.titleauthor dta on dta.title_id = dt.title_id
left join dbo.authors da on da.au_id = dta.au_id
left join dbo.publishers dp on dp.pub_id = dt.pub_id
group by dt.title;
```

And then shortly realized that it would not work because while `da.au_fname` and `da.au_lname` are *associated* with `dt` through `dta`, `dp.pub_name` is *associated* directly with `dt`. Each title has only one publisher, so there must be a solution, right?

Thank you.

Comment: If ther eis only one publisher per title, then why not just group by publisher too?

Comment: Oh, duh... Thank you. `group by dp.pub_name, dt.title`. You should put that in an answer so I can mark it.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Here comes the answer in 3, 2, 1...

Comment: When I wish to make a wish I wave my hand with a great swish swish!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one publisher per title, then just group by publisher too. Said another way, if the relationship from title to publisher is singular with respect to title (a publisher might have many titles, but a title has one publisher) then saying `GROUP BY publisher, title` is as divisive as saying `GROUP BY title`

Pubisher ABC has 3 books, "Cats", "Dogs" and "Pigs"

```
SELECT title, GROUP BY title
Cats
Dogs
Pigs
```

Adding publisher to both changes nothing:

```
SELECT publisher, title GROUP BY publisher, title
ABC, Cats
ABC, Dogs
ABC, Pigs
```

Still got 3 records..

If you throw the authors in there too, and each book is authored by two people:

```
SELECT publisher, title, author 
ABC, Cats, John
ABC, Cats, Jane
ABC, Dogs, Tim
ABC, Dogs, Terence
ABC, Pigs, Emma
ABC, Pigs, Sam
```

But then you group by the pub/title and agg the authors:

```
SELECT publisher, title, AGG(author) GROUP BY publisher, title
ABC, Cats, "John,Jane"
ABC, Dogs, "Tim,Terence"
ABC, Pigs, "Emma,Sam"
```

Then you're back to 3 rows (the distinct values of publisher and title) and the agg'd values that used to be on their own rows/causing a repetition of the pub+title data, are on a single line

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, just adding `pub_name` to the `group by` would work:

```
select dt.title,
       STRING_AGG(CONCAT(da.au_fname, ' ', da.au_lname), ', ') as authors,
       dp.pub_name
from dbo.titles dt left join
     dbo.titleauthor dta
     on dta.title_id = dt.title_id left join 
     dbo.authors da
     on da.au_id = dta.au_id left join
     dbo.publishers dp
     on dp.pub_id = dt.pub_id
group by dt.title, dp.pub_name;
```

Alternatively, you could leave the `group by` as is and use an aggregation function in the `select`:

```
select dt.title,
       STRING_AGG(CONCAT(da.au_fname, ' ', da.au_lname), ', ') as authors,
       max(dp.pub_name)
```